# IdentityServer3 No scopeclaims when using reference token

Tags: identityserver3

In IdentityServer I've added a new scope like this:

```
new Scope
 {
     Name = "myscope",
     Description = "myscope",
     Type=ScopeType.Resource,
     ShowInDiscoveryDocument= false,
     Emphasize = false,
     //AccessTokenType=1, //Reference
     AccessTokenType=0, //JWT
     Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
     {
         new ScopeClaim("location"),
     }
```

I've added a client:

```
new Client
{
    ClientName = "myclient",
    Enabled = true,
    ClientId = "myclient",
    Flow = Flows.Implicit,
    AllowedScopes = new List<string> {"myscope"},
    Claims = new List<Claim> {new Claim("location", "datacenter")}
}
```

I've added an implementation of GetProfileData :

```
public override async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
     await base.GetProfileDataAsync(context);
     if (context.AllClaimsRequested)
         context.IssuedClaims = context.Subject.Claims;
     else if (context.RequestedClaimTypes != null)
              context.IssuedClaims = context.Subject.Claims.Where(claim => context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(claim.Type)).ToList();
 }
```

In my webapi, I'm using AccessTokenValidation:

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "http://localhost:5300",
    AllowedScopes = { "myscope" },
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
});

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("location", policy => policy.RequireClaim("location"));
 });
```

My controller is prefixed with:

```
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer", Policy = "location")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    ...
}
```

Now, when the accesstoken is set to JWT, this works fine, I'm able to call the endpoint. Now, if I change AccessTokenType to reference token, it fails...
If I inspect the RequestedClaimTypes during the call to the profiledata endpoint, it holds the claims for 'myscope' when using JWT, but not when using Reference Token...
Am I missing some configuration or is this the way it's supposed work?? I would have expected to get the same claims in both setup

Answer (score 0):

Reference Tokens are not self-contained tokens like JWTs are.  They provide an ID that can be used to fetch the information that the reference token represents from a backing store.

If you're using IdentityServer3 out of the box, you should be able to request your reference token from the `POST /connect/token` endpoint and follow that up with a request to the token introspection endpoint:

```
POST /connect/accesstokenvalidation
token={tokenReceivedFromPreviousRequest}
```

This will return the information for that reference token that is kept in its backing store, including scopes.

As a note, that introspection endpoint accepts both Reference Tokens and JWTs.

Comment: [This Dominick Baier post](https://leastprivilege.com/2015/11/25/reference-tokens-and-introspection/) goes into more detail about Reference Tokens and introspection if you're interested